# Proper s3 permissions for users uploading image files with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, railstutorial.org, amazon-iam

At the end of Chapter 11 of The Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl I successfully managed to enable user uploads to Amazons S3 service by creating a bucket, using IAM to set a user and granting the user an AmazonS3FullAccess policy.  It feels dirty and very insecure to allow an unknown user on my website to have full access to a bucket for image upload on my website and I'm not sure if I should feel this way.  I created a custom policy at

- http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Which is the following:

```
   {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "Stmt1445501067518",
          "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        }
      ]
   }
```

I am not confident in my solution and could not find any answers googling for the best way to go about this.  I am using carrierwave (with intentions of using carrierwave_direct for my own project), fog, and mini_magick gems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best and probably the most secure way of allowing users to upload files to your site (ie. S3) is to use Browser-Based Post Uploads.

This lets users upload directly to S3 without having to go through your servers. On your servers you simply create a request signature using your access keys.

You can read more about it here:
[Browser Based Uploads Using Post](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html)

I'm not familiar with carrierwave myself but you may find this useful:
[Uploading directly to S3 in rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails)

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will check this out.

Comment: Doesn't this open you up to having users upload petabytes of data to S3 on your dime?