# Store file to amazon s3 rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a working heroku app. But since heroku doesn't provide persistent file storage, I'd like to use amazon s3.
I found heroku tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3
But it seems confusing to me and may be a little bit complicated.
Right now I use carrierwave gem for storing files.

So may be you can give me a small and simple example of code u use to store files to amazon file storage?

UPDATE:
I found this code(is it that simple just a few lines in carrierwave, add gem called fog and that's all? or will I need something else?):

```
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id      => "YOUR AMAZON ACCESS KEY",
      :aws_secret_access_key  => "YOUR AMAZON SECRET KEY",
      :region                 => 'us-west-1' # Change this for different AWS region. Default is 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = "bucket-name"
end
```

Comment: Do you already have an account at Amazon AWS ? Do you have the credentials for the S3 service ? Do you have a bucket created ?

Comment: I don't know what is bucket. Answer to another questions is no, not yet.

Comment: You need to subscribe to Amazon AWS first, then you can start to use their services, for that they will give you credentials, which will be use by your application. It means that you application can put/delete stuff in your bucket. A bucket, to keep it simple, is a folder on AWS S3, where you can put files over there.

Comment: that part I understand, and it seems not a big deal, i will do it of course. Right now, I am trying to figure what to do when I'll have all this credentials.

Comment: @ValterHenrique see an update=)

Comment: I have seen the updated question, it looks exactly what I said, you will need these informations prior. So, create you new account, set your bucket and then try to do a simple upload using your application. :)

Comment: @ValterHenrique okay I got aws_secret_access_key and aws_access_key_id but where do I get a bucket name?

Comment: oh I guess I found where to create bucket=) do I need just its name?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276512/proper-s3-permissions-for-users-uploading-image-files-with-carrierwave/33380527#33380527